# How to NOT include another Django template by default while keeping the tag in the template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following

in settings/base.py

```
SOME_TEMPLATE = os.getenv("SOME_TEMPLATE", "something/template.html")

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # i skip ....
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                # i skip...
                # for the project-specific context
                "core.context_processors.settings_values",
            ],

        },
    },
]
```

then in core/context_processors.py

```
from django.conf import settings


def settings_values(request):
    """
    Returns settings context variable.
    """
    # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    return {
        "SOME_TEMPLATE": settings.SOME_TEMPLATE,
    }
```

in the actual template

```
{% include SOME_TEMPLATE %}
```

Without changing or removing  `{% include SOME_TEMPLATE %}` what can I do such that by default, the template is not included? Preferably at the settings level?

I was thinking of using if tag but i felt it would be more verbose.

e.g.

```
    {% if SOME_TEMPLATE %}
    {% include SOME_TEMPLATE %}
    {% endif %}
```

Is there a way to be less verbose and still achieve the same outcome?

Comment: What do you want to cause the template to be included? Is an if tag really too verbose?

Comment: when the setting in the base.py or in the .env has some value then the template is included. otherwise, don't include. 
the if tag turns a 1 line into 3 lines. so.. i was hoping there's another way around i.t

Comment: Could you just create an empty template and point your setting to this empty template when you don't want it included?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution seems to be: a fallback empty template as suggested by Iain Shelvington

An other solution could be to write a specific `templatetag` to do the job exactly as you want

in `<your_app>/templatetag/my_include.py`

```py
@register.inclusion_tag("tags/my_include.html", takes_context=True)
def ms1_top_menu_children(context, template_var):
    include_context = {
        "template_var": template_var,
    }

    # if you need all the context in the included template ...
    include_context.update(context)
    # if you need all the context in the included template ...

    return include_context
```

in `<your_app>/templates/tags/my_include.html`

```html
    {% if template_var %}
        {% include template_var %}
    {% endif %}
```

in your html pages

```html
    {% load my_include %}


...

    {% my_include SOME_TEMPLATE %}

...
```

**NB:** this way you can also move all the `settings_values(request)` code in the `templatetag` code ...